# Has anyone managed to build the STAF framework on raspberry pi with os raspbian v9?

Tags: raspberry-pi, automation, raspbian, build, makefile

STAF (Software Testing Automation Framework) is a open source framework for testing automation http://staf.sourceforge.net/index.php.

It is supported for several platform but not yet for raspberry, so there isn't makefile! 
Below the list of binaries is available source code 
http://staf.sourceforge.net/getcurrent.php.

I'd like that it build for Raspberry pi 3+ with rasbian v9.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully built STAF 3.4.26 on Pi 3/4 with the following environment:

```
export PROJECTS="staf connprov*"
export OS_NAME=linux
export BUILD_TYPE=retail
export OPENSSL_LIBDIRS=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
export OPENSSL_VERSION=1.0.2
make $@
```